# present perfect vs progressive form

Tags: tense

I found the sentence below on the Internet.

> [Part of the water reaching the ground infiltrates and percolates down
>   to form the groundwater.](http://www.csun.edu/~vchsc006/553/457.html)

Can this be rewritten as follows:?

> Part of the water **that has reached** the ground infiltrates and
>   percolates down to form the groundwater.

In my language, the latter sounds more natural.

Comment: Yes, they are essentially the same. You can say either and they both sound fine in idiomatic English.

Comment: @PeterJennings I am trying to write an answer, but I can't seem to be able to come up with anything other than "yes, it can".

Comment: @AIQ Much the same here.